# A weird casting issue using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, casting

I am facing a weird behaviour using the TF module when trying to output a float from a user-defined function to be wrapped by TF.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_func(x):
  outX = 1.0
  return outX

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(2,))
resultFun = tf.py_func(my_func, [input], tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  inival=[np.array(0.9),np.array(1.9)]
  print(sess.run(resultFun, feed_dict={input: inival}))
```

The issue is at the line

```
outX=1.0
```

since it generates the following:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): 0-th value returned by pyfunc_0 is double, but expects float

I tried to force the cast with np.float or float but same results.
Actually I also managed to overcame it with a trick:

```
outX = x*0+1.0
```

and it works.
So it clearly depends on some kind of mis-casting. 
How do I solve the casting issue with no shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Usually TensorFlow tries to fit native Python values to the requested data type, but it can get confused sometimes. In this case, since Python itself does not allow you to specify whether the value is 32 or 64 bits, you can just wrap it with NumPy:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def my_func(x):
  outX = np.array(1.0, dtype=np.float32)
  return outX

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(2,))
resultFun = tf.py_func(my_func, [input], tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  inival=[np.array(0.9),np.array(1.9)]
  print(sess.run(resultFun, feed_dict={input: inival})) 
  # 0.1
```